# Работа с sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3

Добрый вечер. Я немного не понимаю как реализовать... Смотрите, подключаюсь к БД и делаю выборку

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('****');

$results = $db->query('SELECT player FROM **** ');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

Но в результате выводится ( [0] => Madii [player] => Madii )... Мне нужно на выходе получить только Madii. Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так... На [сайте php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) сижу невылазно... Но проблема в том что там всё на английском(не всё понимаю), да и вообще в программировании новичок. Спасибо большое.

Comment: если на сайте php в адресной строке подменить en на ru, то произойдет небольшая магия

Comment: print_r($row[0]['Madii [player]']);

Или если нужно разбирать массив $row, по частям, то смотрите в сторону: 

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [докам](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php), нужно сделать вот так:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('****');

$results = $db->query('SELECT player FROM **** ', SQLITE3_ASSOC);
$playerNames = array(); // инициализируем массив для имен игроков
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    $playerNames[] = $row['player']; // добавляем в массив новый элемент, доставая его из массива $row
}
print_r($playerNames);
?>
```

По умолчанию вторым параметром идет SQLITE3_BOTH, который возвращает все поля как по цифровым, так и по именным ключам.

update: я тупой, только сейчас понял какой вывод требуется, обновил ответ.

Comment: Дададада. Я только что сам нашёл. Вот пришёл написать вам. Смотрел код на сайте http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/ и там увидел пример реализации, просто добавил  print_r($row['player']);. Огромнейшее вам спасибо. Прошу прощения за мои глупые вопросы. Всего вам хорошего, надеюсь когда нибудь буду так же хорошо разбираться во всём этом как вы.

Comment: @istimbi, весь этот сайт существует для того, чтобы задавались вопросы, на которые давались верные ответы. Я тут иногда появляюсь с вопросами того же начального уровня по С, например